# how to make achanges to an already deployed meteor app in windows

Tags: javascript, deployment, meteor

I have an already deployed meteor app on a digital ocean server. I need to add just a few lines of code and make the changes.
Is there any other method rather than using meteor up as it requires ubuntu and im using windows 7, i dont want to use  virtual box.

Comment: Can you ssh into your digital ocean box and make the change there?

Comment: I would ssh in, then using meteor up deploy your app on the vps. That's how I deploy my always-running apps. Basically move your whole project over then `mup deploy`. In fact, I sftp into my vps and work directly on it, regardless of the platform/console I'm using.

Comment: You can deploy with either meteor deploy or modulus deploy. Check out https://modulus.io/